# Continuous current of a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I am trying to build a 60 V-20 A power switch using P-channel  MOSFET. I found this MOSFET provided by Vishay.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am a little bit confused about the continuous drain current of this MOSFET, at Tc=25c is 37.1 A, and at Ta=25c is 9.2 A so what is the actual drain current, and is it suitable for my analog switch (60 V-20 A)?

Comment: khalil_emdev - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which says that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied from elsewhere, that copied content must be correctly referenced. The source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked as a minimum (references for books / articles should include title, author(s), publisher, edition, page numbers etc.). Therefore please can you [edit] your question to include the link(s) for the original source(s) for those images. Thanks. (As you are new here, please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules & etiquette.)

Answer (score 5):

> *I am a little bit confused about the continuous drain current of this
> MOSFET, at Tc=25c is 37.1A, and at Ta=25c is 9.2A so what is the
> actual drain current*

If the ambient temperature (Ta) is held at 25 °C and, by using an infinite heatsink, the case temperature (Tc) is also held at ambient, then the absolute maximum current that the device can conduct is 37.1 amps.

If the device were unattached from the infinite heatsink and, was deployed as per the data sheet notes (it will specify some copper PCB area) then, the maximum current it can handle is 9.2 amps.

Whether it can be used within your design is impossible to say but, here are some guidelines: -

- The absolute current values (from above) are when the device is fully activated **and not** used in a linear fashion so, be aware of this
- You should check the safe operating area graph in the [data sheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/73444/sud50p10.pdf): -

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Current is dependent on how well you cool the package.

> Tc=25c is 37.1A

If you can keep the case at 25 C, then 37.1 A will heat the junction to its maximum permitted temperature of 175 C. Hint, you're not going to be able to keep the case at 25 C, even with a large heatsink.

> and at Ta=25c is 9.2A

note b specifies using a 'heatsink' of a 1" square of FR4 board. You might be happy to use a heatsink this small for low power applications. With this heatsink, the case will get quite hot and the junction reach 175 C with 9.2 A.

In practice, with a decent heatsink, you will probably achieve a case temperature somewhere between the two. The data sheet will contain design values for the thermal resistance, so you will be able to compute max current for any given case temperature.

There are two more things to consider before you design for current

1. These are **absolute maximum** ratings. You do not want to run at these continuously, or you will get a severely limited lifetime, and zero headroom to absorb any other accidental abuse. Run at their recommended operating conditions, which will be rather less than the abs max.
2. As you switch the FET on or off, it will dissipate an additional pulse of energy. If it's merely a switch for a load, you can ignore the switching energy. If it's in a switch mode power supply and this energy is getting dissipated 10s or 100s of thousand times per second, you will need to design for it